# Can I make the changeset comment required?

Tags: liquibase

I would like to enforce comments are provide for changesets.  Is there any way I can make the comment element mandatory for changesets?

Answer (score 0):

Not with just Liquibase. You would need to pre-process the changelog yourself. You could do this by writing a Liquibase extension, or you could do it with some other method. If you are using XML formatted changelogs, you could use any of the many XML libraries to do this verification.